# Need javascript for buttons to appear/disapear at specific times of day

Tags: javascript, timer, scheduled-tasks, schedule

I'm working within a CMS that gives limited options - I'm in need of a Javascript or JQuery method to create buttons that appear for 30 minute intervals about 5 times per day. To complicate matters, the times of day change for weekend days. I'm a beginner with those coding languages, but I'm cornered into using them by my CMS.

Logically, here's what I think I need to do:
Find the day of the week (Mon-Fri leads to one schedule, Sat-Sun leads to the other)
Find the time of day and display if within 30 minutes of a trigger time.

Any coaching with the code or approach would be greatly appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: Be aware that if you're using JavaScript or JQuery you're reliant upon the accuracy and time zone of the user of the system, not the server you're running the system from.

Comment: @AdrianWragg Unless OP uses AJAX to communicate with server to check the time before show/hiding buttons.

Comment: @gibberish Quite true, yes.

Comment: OP: Do you need it to be static to your time zone, or based on the user's time zone?

Answer (score 0):

```
var foo=(new Date);
//get current date
foo.getDay();
//get current day
if(foo>5){
//weekend
}else{
//weekday
}
setInterval(function(){},1000)
//run a function every second (1000 millisecond)
```

I suggest checking the minutes of the current date at a set interval.
if the minutes are lower than 5 or between 30 and 35, show the button
else, hide the button.

```
$("button").show()
$("button").hide()
```

Answer (score 0):

This will give you the current time:

```
var date = new Date();
var hours = date.getHours();
var minutes = date.getMinutes();
```

If you use this in an interval running every hour, it will work perfectly:

```
$("#btn").hide();

//Run every hour
setInterval(function() {
        checkButton();
    }, 3600000);    //1000 milliseconds * 60 seconds * 60 minutes

function checkButton() {
    var date = new Date();
    var hours = date.getHours();
    var minutes = date.getMinutes();

    //Show button at 5:30 PM
    if(hours == 17 && minutes == 30) {
        $("#btn").show();
    }
    //Hide button at 6:00 PM
    if(hours == 18 && minutes == 0) {
        $("#btn").hide();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is a solution that depends on the server to say whether the button should be displayed.

I noted that other answers pretty much depend on the user remaining on the page to determine if the button should appear/disappear. What about a condition where users are coming to the page at various times of day and the button must either be visible or not?

This solution will run whenever the page is viewed, not just every *nn* minutes (as determined by the user's browser). Therefore, it will work for new visitors, but can also be configured to run periodically for those already on the page (via setInterval -- see other answers for code examples).

Note that I have added a few unnecessary bits (such as over-riding the current time) so the OP can forcibly simulate different times of day.

This is a fully-working example; just copy/paste into two files:
1. index.php (or whatever.php)
2. my_php_processor_file.php (if change this name, must also change reference to it in ajax code block)

**index.php** *(includes HTML / jQuery):*

```
<html>
    <head>

        <script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

        <script type="text/javascript">

            $(document).ready(function() {

                //runs on page load
                do_ajax();

                //manual run via button click
                $('#gobutt').click(function() {
                    do_ajax();
                });

                function do_ajax() {
                    //get user-supplied time for OP to test
                    utime = $('#params').val();

                    //contact server to see if time to show button
                    $.ajax({
                        type: "POST",
                        url: "my_php_processor_file.php",
                        data: 'usertime=' + utime, //only needed during OP testing time override
                        success:function(data){
                            //display report from server
                            $('#reportdiv').html(data);

                            //show or hide button
                            if (data=='yes') {
                                $('#mybutt').show();
                            }else{
                                $('#mybutt').hide();
                            }
                        } //END ajax success function

                    }); //END ajax code block

                } //END do_ajax() function

            }); //END $(document).ready()

        </script>
    </head>

<body>

    Insert time to check if button will appear:<br />
    <input id="params" type="text" value="13:30" /><br />
    <input id="gobutt" type="button" value="Submit Now" />
    <br /><br /><br />

    Results from Server:<br />
    <div id="reportdiv"></div>
    <input id="mybutt" type="button" value="Appears Only At Certain Times" style="display:none" />


</body>
</html>
```

---

**my_php_processor_file.php**

```
<?php

//Get time on server in associative array (source: http://ca3.php.net/manual/en/function.localtime.php)
$localtime_assoc = localtime(time(), true);

//If a user-specified time provided in the #params input element:
if (isset($_POST['usertime']) == true) {
    if ($_POST['usertime'] != '') {
        //over-ride time from server with user-supplied values
        $aUT = explode(':', $_POST['usertime']);
        $localtime_assoc['tm_hour'] = $aUT[0];
        $localtime_assoc['tm_min'] = $aUT[1];
    }
}

//Hours when button should appear
$aHours = array('6', '9', '12', '15', '19', '21');


if ( in_array($localtime_assoc['tm_hour'], $aHours) ) {
    //button appears only in last 30 mins of hour
    if ( $localtime_assoc['tm_min'] >= 30 ) {
        echo 'yes';
    }else{
        echo 'right hour, wrong half hour';
    }

}else{
    echo 'Server time: ' . $localtime_assoc['tm_hour'] .":". $localtime_assoc['tm_min'] . " o'clock";
}
```

---

For identifying the day of the week, use **nrkkalyan**'s code example at bottom of this page:

http://php.net/manual/en/function.jddayofweek.php

Answer (score 0):

I decided to take the plunge, given my previous warnings about reliance upon the client's time, and write a pure JavaScript version:

```
var timeList = [
    { 'days': [0,1,2,3,4], 'times': [ [ 10, 18 ], [12, 30] ] },
    { 'days': [5,6], 'times': [ [ 10,30 ], [12, 30] ] }
];

var minutesNearTimeListToShow = 30;
var pollSeconds = 60;

$(document).ready(function() {
    checkForShowing();
});

function checkForShowing() {

    var now = new Date();
    var currentDay = now.getDay();
    var currentHour = now.getHours();
    var currentMinute = now.getMinutes();
    var timeAndDay = getNextTimeAndDay (currentDay, currentHour, currentMinute);

    var nextAlertDue = new Date(now.getYear() + 1900, now.getMonth(), now.getDate(), timeAndDay.hour, timeAndDay.minute);
    nextAlertDue.setDate(now.getDate() - currentDay + timeAndDay.day);

    var differenceSeconds = (nextAlertDue - now) / 1000;

    if (differenceSeconds < minutesNearTimeListToShow * 60) {

        $(".myButton").show();
        window.setTimeout (function() {
            $(".myButton").hide();
        }, differenceSeconds * 1000);

    } else {
        $(".myButton").hide();
        window.setTimeout(checkForShowing, pollSeconds * 1000);
    }

}

function getNextTimeAndDay(tDay, tHour, tMinute) {

    var times = getTimesForDay(tDay);
    var nextTime = getNextTime (tHour, tMinute, times)

    if (!nextTime) {
        tHour = 0;
        tMinute = 0;        
        tDay++;
        if (tDay == 7) { tDay = 0; }
        times = getTimesForDay(tDay);
        nextTime = getNextTime (tHour, tMinute, times);
    }

    return { day: tDay, hour: nextTime[0], minute: nextTime[1] };

}

function getNextTime (tHour, tMinute, times) {

    for (var i in times) {
        if ((tHour < times[i][0]) || (tHour == times[i][0] && tMinute <= times[i][1])) {
            return times[i];
        }
    }

    return false;

}

function getTimesForDay(currentDay) {

    var times = false;

    for (var i in timeList) {
        var days = timeList[i].days;
        if (days.indexOf(currentDay) > -1) {
            times =  timeList[i].times;
        }
    }

    return times;

}
```

The main configuration is right at the top, allowing different times to be specified for different days.

Once a minute, the code will check to see if it is within half an hour of one of these times; if it is, then the button will be shown and a `setTimeout` set up to hide it again (and restart polling) when the half-hour is up.

Note that if the code starts within the half-hour (e.g. 20 minutes in), it will pick up on that, show the button, and schedule the hiding for just 10 minutes later.

The date checking is reasonably well tested, the scheduling not so much - feel free to suggest corrections!